# Eclipse r.java build failure

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

Been searching for quite a while and have yet to stumble across a solution on this site or others. For some reason (even after a fresh install of the eclipse/ADK tools) the r.java file is not generating. Even when a new project is created there is no r.java. Tried the typical clean/build solution. Any guesses?

Comment: build,clean & restart eclipse after restart again build and clean.

Comment: tried deleting gen and bin?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean the project. Its a problem of the IDE. Try cleaning and building.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse,

check `project.properties` file exists or not. If not, you can copy it from some other project. It is also possible that some hidden files are getting missed while copying project, which cant be created again by eclipse

Check Android jar file exists or not in project.